# Why can you return a const char* in main?

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain how this code doesn't give errors when compiled?

```
int main()
{
  // why doesn't the following line give a type mismatch error??/
  return "success!";
}
```

Comment: `t.cpp:4:10: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'const char [9]'`

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23269

Comment: I thought it was explained pretty well at codegolf.

Comment: @juanchopanza: my compiler ignores trigraphs by default. My comment was to address the question in the title - i.e. you can't.

Comment: it seems people are pissed off by the question and down voting it, but i did learn from this question and more importantly answer from @juanchopanza, +1 for both :)

Comment: @Mat Right you are, removed my comment.

Comment: @Mat What command do I use to turn trigraphs off?

Comment: @user3398519 You shouldn't switch them off if you want your code to be portable.

Comment: Depends on your compiler. GCC has it off by default but gives you a warning when you encounter one. clang has it off by default too and you need `-trigraphs` to enable them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of the trigraph `??/`, which is replaced by a `\`, meaning the return is commented out. Your code is equivalent to

```
int main()
{
  // why doesn't the following line give a type mismatch error\
  return "success!";
}
```

which is the same as

```
int main()
{
  // why doesn't the following line give a type mismatch error return "success!";
}
```

Also note that, in the absence of a `return` statement in `main`, there is an implicit `return 0;`, so the code is well defined.

Comment: If `??/` will be \, why `return "success!";` is commented out?

Comment: +1 for even thinking of trigraphs. i wonder how much time the OP used on *constructing* the question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: none at all, it was posted on Code Golf not long ago (along with an explanation)

Comment: @MarounMaroun The backslash joins the lines together.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I must admit I cheated. I tried to compile the code with and got a pretty useful error message: `warning: trigraph ??/ converted to \ [-Wtrigraphs]`. I hadn't even seen the trailing `/`, so I assumed OP had an old/not very standards compliant compiler.